# knowing when dynamically added data in div finished loading

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, dom

I am loading html data via ajax, containing images, into a div on my page using

```
$('#container').html(data)
```

assuming that the variable data is what the ajax returned,
how can i know when the new data (and images) finished loading in the container?

Comment: Are you really interested in knowing when the loaded data is inserted into the container? That should happen almost instantly. Maybe you're really interested in when your ajax call finished fetching the data and is ready to insert it into the container? For that, jQuery ajax function offer to add callback functions.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `.promise().done()`. These are also useful in situations like when you want to wait for any and all animations running on a collection or jQuery object to finish, without passing your code in individual callbacks.

If what you are looking to do is call code or a handler on content that is loaded then you should look at the `.load()` event and delegated event handlers. You may not need both, but you should read, know, and understand them anyway. You can read about delegated event handlers in the docs for the `.on()` method.

**Quick Summary of Delegated Event Handlers**

Delegated event handlers are handlers that you attach to an ancestor element of the content (which may or may not have been loaded yet) that you want to listen on.

The following is an example of a delegated `click` handler being bound to the `body` element and set to listen for a `click` event on a descendant element with class `foo`. This means this handler will listen to any and every element with class `foo` (even those that are added later and not yet loaded into the DOM) that is a descendant of the `body` element.

```
$("body").on("click", ".foo", function() {
    bar();
});
```

The below does exactly the same thing, except that it only binds the handler to those `.foo` elements that exist at the time the handler is bound. The handler will not listen to any `.foo` elements added later.

```
$(".foo").on("click", function () { 
   bar();
});
```

By passing the a selector argument to the `.on()` method, you can tell jQuery that rather than listen for the specified event to happen on the bound element, it should instead listen for a propagated (or bubbled) event that originated from a descendant matching the given selector to reach the bound element, and should call the handler using the descendant that triggered the event as the the context object (`this`) for the handler.

**Relevant Links to jQuery's API**

- [deferred.promise() docs](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/)
- [deferred.done() docs](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)
- [.load() docs](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)
- [.on() docs](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: .promise().done() is triggering once the command (html(data)) is done. not when the content are finished loading.
I need to know when the content especially images finished loading

Comment: I updated my answer with what you asked for, `.load()`, and what I think you are really looking for, which is delegated event handlers using `.on()`.

Comment: following your steps, 
i added
$("body").on("load", "#container", function() {
 alert('loaded');
});

however, this did not fire :/ what am I missing ?

Comment: That event handler would fire when the browser finished loading the `#container` element, not when something happens later to the `#container` element. Additionally, you need to be careful when to add the event handler. If you add that code simply to the `<head>`, it won't fire, because at that point the `<body>` won't yet be there to add an event handler to. You might want to look into jQuery's [ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function. But I'm not sure it'll help with your original problem.

Comment: sorry for the long delay. but i'm still not able to solve this matter.
i tried adding the event in the ajax call. but still not doing me any good.

what could be the best way to know when the html added through ajax is done loading in the container? thanks